# Not sending push notifications

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-push, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem regarding push notifications. I have this error in firebase functions logs:

> Error: To send a message with a payload, the subscription must have
>   'auth' and 'p256dh' keys.

```
 exports.storePostData = functions.https.onRequest(
 (request, response) => {
     cors(request, response, () => {
         admin.database().ref('posts').push({
             id: request.body.id,
             title: request.body.title,
             location: request.body.location,
             image: request.body.image
         }).then(() => {
             webpush.setVapidDetails('mailto: xxxx@gmail.com', 'BLl7xIPAyJNzsMi5vo_aG-4RdXdyZ4Q4ZFpTgnm902qN79MIiSORBk9N-rfFEGiKNPuJu5SJmUX35Wwce9nuH94', 'M8E6hw7jCmu7qNQJ88FV5o02OAiLefEFJK8jyJimk7g')

             return admin.database().ref('subscriptions').once('value');
         }).then(subscriptions => {
             subscriptions.forEach(sub => {
                 var pushConfig = {
                     endpoint: sub.val().endpoint,
                     keys: {
                         auth: sub.val().keys,
                         p256dh: sub.val().p256dh
                     }
                 }
                 webpush.sendNotification(pushConfig, JSON.stringify({
                     title: 'New Post',
                     content: 'New post added',
                     openUrl: '/help'
                 })).catch(err => {
                     console.log(err)
                 })
             })
             response.status(201).json({
                 message: 'Data stored',
                 id: request.body.id
             })
         }).catch(err => {
             response.status(500).json({
                 error: err
             })
         })
     })
 });
```

This is my function for storing post data, and i think the problem is here because it can't even get to push event in serviceWorker (i don't get any logs there).

Comment: We can't really help without seeing any of your code...

Comment: Yea, sorry about that, i edited..

Answer (score 2):

On the client side, you should be able to retrieve subscription
On Angular it would be like

```
    const sw = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('/assets/js/service-worker.js', { scope: '/assets/js/' });

      let subscription = await sw.pushManager.getSubscription();
```

Through this way, you should be able to get subscription and subscription object contains p256dh and auth keys.

You should be able to see the values by

```
      console.log("subscription: ", subscription?.toJSON());
```

Answer (score 1):

Ye i figured it need to go as:

```
keys: {
  auth: sub.val().keys.auth,
  p256dh: sub.val().keys.p256dh
}
```